# Unable to execute php function in wordpress as meta contains apostrophe

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use the function below to display the fiance's name of the current user but i am unable to do this due to the apostrophe in Fiance's as the code stop working from the apostrophe onwards.

Please help on how i can get round this.

```
<?php 
  $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
  $key = 'Fiance's Name';
  $single = true; 
  $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
  echo $user_last; 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes here: `$key = "Fiance's Name";`

Comment: This is definitely the correction to the problem you listed above. If your code still doesn't work there's another problem.

Comment: Thanks..there seemed to have been a pluggin conflict

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use `\` or `"`

```
  $key = 'Fiance\'s Name';
```

or

```
  $key = "Fiance\'s Name";

 echo addslashes($user_last);
```